# PDFview scrollview zoom

Tags: ios, swift, zooming, pdfkit, pdfview

I am working in pdf editing project, in that I have to add signature in pdfview and after that need to resize and delete that signature. Now for this I am adding one scrollview with UIView on top of pdfview with transparent alpha and add image view to that UIView but I had an issue with zooming. How can I get how much zoom pdfview zooming when user pinch zoom. I want to find pdfview's zoom contentInset, so I can set my own scrollview's contentInset.

try to get pdfview scale factor when pdfview zoom with :

```
@objc func pdfViewScaleChange(notification:NSNotification){
        print(self.pdfView.scaleFactor)
}
```

But Still I can't find How can I zoom and set my UIScrollview as pdfview zoom.

Answer (score 2):

Your PDFView has a property called `scaleFactorForSizeToFit`, which is the scale factor that PDFKits `autoScales` would use for scaling the current document and layout.

What this means is that if you use the `autoScales` property when you set your pdf you will be able to calculate an amount to scale your UIScrollview by.

Here is an example of what I mean for some more context:

```
//wherever you set your pdf (doesn't have to be viewDidAppear)
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    pdfView.document = PDFDocument(data: data)
    pdfView.autoScales = true

    //Add the observer here to detect when your pdf is zoomed in or out
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                 selector: #selector(pdfPageWasZoomed),
                                     name: Notification.Name.PDFViewPageChanged,
                                               object: nil)
}

//wherever you want to zoom use this
func getScrollViewScaleFactor() -> CGFloat {
    return (pdfView.scaleFactor / pdfView.scaleFactorForSizeToFit)   
}

//Objc function which is called everytime the zoom changes
@objc private func pdfPageWasZoomed() {
    //Here use the function getScrollViewScaleFactor() to get a factor to scale in or out by
}
```

Something like this should solve your problem.